# Concurrently run Express and Create-React-App issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I've built a simple base application using Express and Create-React-App (http://myfirst-reactapp.herokuapp.com/). My project is split into two parts: one is the server (it has a package.json and an index.js file) and the other one is the client (which was created using npm create-react-app).
I am trying to redirect the users from the server side to the client side (For example localhost:5000/test will redirect to localhost:3000/test), but after deploying it to **Heroku**, I got the following error, and could not find an answer that solves the issue:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

#### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('/client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

#### package.json (server)

```
{
  "name": "heroku_base",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.2",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `main.js` file isn't loading correctly. Instead of JS it's loading your root page it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the index.html file for every request to the express server.

Try removing this code

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Also, you should probably replace

```
app.use(express.static('/client/build'));
```

With something like

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Do you have any idea how I can redirect the user to index.html whenever he enters the "/" (default) root? That is why I included the "index.html" part in my code.

Comment: Well my express with react embedded app does exactly what I showed you and it returns index.html by default when user requests root.

Is it not doing that for you?